# HTML elements in schema.org module

Tags: 7

I am using the Schema.org module for schema tags, I tried to add html elements    but they never get printed. Is it possible to do this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Look at schema.org (the website) or somewhere else and check of links are supported at all. If yes, file a bug report on [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/schemaorg?categories=All).

Comment: As far as I know, schema.org is text only. No HTML.